# Why can't I call my Redux action creators from my event handler function but I can from componentWillMount()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm working on an app using React, Redux, and TypeScript.

I have a Redux store setup which sets initial state and successfully populates my components. I'm now trying to wire up a form that will call my action creator that retrieves data from a controller with filter values.

I'm using connect to access the action creators through props.

I can call my action creators from componentWillMount() but if I make the same call inside my form submission handler function I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestVersions' of undefined

**This is my Redux enabled component:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, NavLink, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from '../../store';
import * as ASVersionQueueState from '../../store/ASVersionQueue';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import SimpleGridExample from "./SimpleGridExample";
import ASVersionQueueBulkActions from "./ASVersionQueueBulkActions";
import ASVersionQueueFilters from "./ASVersionQueueFilters";
import DataGridStats from "../common/DataGridStats";
import PageTitleHeader from "../common/PageTitleHeader";

type ASVersionQueueProps =
    ASVersionQueueState.ASVersionQueueState             // ... state we've requested from the Redux store
    & typeof ASVersionQueueState.actionCreators       // ... plus action creators we've requested
    & RouteComponentProps<{}>;                      // ... plus incoming routing parameters

class ASVersionQueue extends React.Component<ASVersionQueueProps, {}> {

    handleChange(event: any) {
        console.log('Bulk Action: ' + event.target.value);
        console.log()
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        // This method runs when the component is first added to the page
        // This function call works
        this.props.requestVersions(this.props.versionQueueFilter);
        this.props.requestEmployeesList();
        this.props.requestEventsList();
    }

    handleEventsFilterChange(event: any) {
        console.log('Event Filter: ' + event.target.value);
    }

    handleFilterSubmission() { 
        // I removed my incoming parameters and am simply passing back the current state values to understand the source of my error
        //This function call is throwing the error
        this.props.requestVersions(this.props.versionQueueFilter);
    }

    public render() {
        return <div className="container-fluid">
            <PageTitleHeader
                title="Account Services"
                className="page-title"
            />
            <div className="as-grid grid-controls-container row">
                <div className="col-lg-2 bulk-actions-container">
                    <ASVersionQueueBulkActions
                        outerClassName=""
                        controlClassName=""
                        htmlId="ver-grid-bulk-action"
                        htmlName="ver-grid-bulk-action"
                        onChangeFunction={() => (this.handleChange)}

                    // TO DO: pass down menu options to trigger Redux actions

                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-8 grid-filter-container">
                    <ASVersionQueueFilters 
                        outerClassName=""
                        htmlId=""
                        filterVals={this.props.versionQueueFilter}
                        employeesFilterList={this.props.employeesFilterList}
                        eventsFilterList={this.props.eventsFilterList}
                        onSubmitFunction={this.handleFilterSubmission}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-2 grid-stats-container">
                    <DataGridStats />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="ag-grid full row ag-theme-blue">
                <SimpleGridExample />
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}

// Wire up the React component to the Redux store
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.asVersionQueue,     // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props
    ASVersionQueueState.actionCreators                 // Selects which action creators are merged into the component's props
)(ASVersionQueue) as typeof ASVersionQueue;
```

This is my Redux action creators and reducers:

```
import { fetch, addTask } from 'domain-task';
import { Action, Reducer, ActionCreator } from 'redux';
import { AppThunkAction } from './';
import * as moment from 'moment';

// -----------------
// STATE - This defines the type of data maintained in the Redux store.

export interface ASVersionQueueState {
    queuedVersions: QueuedVersion[];
    versionQueueFilter: VersionQueueFilter;
    eventsFilterList: SelectListItem[];
    employeesFilterList: SelectListItem[];
}

export interface QueuedVersion {
    VersionCode: string;
    VersionQualifier: string;
    VersionID: string;
    ProductID: string;
    PieceName: string;
    PrintClass: string;
    FirstInhomeDate: string;
    AccountID: string;
    AccountExecutive: string;
    AccountManager: string;
    ArtManager: string;
    AdUID: string;
    Status: string;
    Queue: string;
    DueDateOverride: string;
    IsLocked: string;
}

export interface VersionQueueFilter {
    StartDate: string;
    EndDate: string;
    PieceType: Array<string>;
    EventType: Array<string>;
    EventID: string;
    Employee: string;
}

export interface SelectListItem {
    OptionName: string;
    OptionVal: string;
}

let DefaultVersionQueueFilter = {
    StartDate: moment().subtract(30, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    EndDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    PieceType: ['pt-impactpc'],
    EventType: ['et-special'],
    EventID: '',
    Employee: '12345'
}


// -----------------
// ACTIONS - These are serializable (hence replayable) descriptions of state transitions.
// They do not themselves have any side-effects; they just describe something that is going to happen.
// Use @typeName and isActionType for type detection that works even after serialization/deserialization.

interface RequestVersionsAction {
    type: 'REQUEST_VERSIONS';
    versionQueueFilter: VersionQueueFilter;
}

interface ReceiveVersionsAction {
    type: 'RECEIVE_VERSIONS';
    versionQueueFilter: VersionQueueFilter;
    receivedVersions: QueuedVersion[];
}

interface RequestEmployeesListAction {
    type: 'REQUEST_EMPLOYEES_LIST';
}

interface ReceiveEmployeesListAction {
    type: 'RECEIVE_EMPLOYEES_LIST';
    receivedEmployeesList: SelectListItem[];
}

interface RequestEventsListAction {
    type: 'REQUEST_EVENTS_LIST';
}

interface ReceiveEventsListAction {
    type: 'RECEIVE_EVENTS_LIST';
    receivedEventsList: SelectListItem[];
}


// Declare a 'discriminated union' type. This guarantees that all references to 'type' properties contain one of the
// declared type strings (and not any other arbitrary string).
type KnownAction = RequestVersionsAction | ReceiveVersionsAction | RequestEmployeesListAction | ReceiveEmployeesListAction | RequestEventsListAction | ReceiveEventsListAction;

// ----------------
// ACTION CREATORS - These are functions exposed to UI components that will trigger a state transition.
// They don't directly mutate state, but they can have external side-effects (such as loading data).

export const actionCreators = {
    requestVersions: (versionQueueFilter: VersionQueueFilter): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
        console.log('actionCreator requestVersions called...');
        if (versionQueueFilter !== getState().asVersionQueue.versionQueueFilter) {
            let fetchTask = fetch(`api/Versions`)
                .then(response => response.json() as Promise<QueuedVersion[]>)
                .then(data => {
                    dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_VERSIONS', versionQueueFilter: versionQueueFilter, receivedVersions: data });
                    //dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_VERSIONS', receivedVersions: data });
                });

            addTask(fetchTask); // Ensure server-side prerendering waits for this to complete
            dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_VERSIONS', versionQueueFilter: versionQueueFilter });
            //dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_VERSIONS' });
        }
    },
    requestEmployeesList: (): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
        let fetchTask = fetch(`api/EmployeesList`)
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<SelectListItem[]>)
            .then(data => {
                dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_EMPLOYEES_LIST', receivedEmployeesList: data });
            });

        addTask(fetchTask); // Ensure server-side prerendering waits for this to complete
        dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_EMPLOYEES_LIST' });
    },
    requestEventsList: (): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
        let fetchTask = fetch(`api/EventsLIst`)
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<SelectListItem[]>)
            .then(data => {
                dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_EVENTS_LIST', receivedEventsList: data });
            });

        addTask(fetchTask); // Ensure server-side prerendering waits for this to complete
        dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_EVENTS_LIST' });
    }
};

// ----------------
// REDUCER - For a given state and action, returns the new state. To support time travel, this must not mutate the old state.
const unloadedState: ASVersionQueueState = { queuedVersions: [], versionQueueFilter: DefaultVersionQueueFilter, eventsFilterList: [], employeesFilterList: [] };

export const reducer: Reducer<ASVersionQueueState> = (state: ASVersionQueueState, incomingAction: Action) => {
    const action = incomingAction as KnownAction;
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REQUEST_EMPLOYEES_LIST':
            return {
                queuedVersions: state.queuedVersions,
                versionQueueFilter: state.versionQueueFilter,
                eventsFilterList: state.eventsFilterList,
                employeesFilterList: state.employeesFilterList
            }
        case 'REQUEST_EVENTS_LIST':
            return {
                queuedVersions: state.queuedVersions,
                versionQueueFilter: state.versionQueueFilter,
                eventsFilterList: state.eventsFilterList,
                employeesFilterList: state.employeesFilterList
            }
        case 'REQUEST_VERSIONS':
            return {
                queuedVersions: state.queuedVersions,
                versionQueueFilter: state.versionQueueFilter,
                eventsFilterList: state.eventsFilterList,
                employeesFilterList: state.employeesFilterList
            }
        case 'RECEIVE_EMPLOYEES_LIST':
            return {
                queuedVersions: state.queuedVersions,
                versionQueueFilter: state.versionQueueFilter,
                eventsFilterList: state.eventsFilterList,
                employeesFilterList: action.receivedEmployeesList
            }
        case 'RECEIVE_EVENTS_LIST':
            return {
                queuedVersions: state.queuedVersions,
                versionQueueFilter: state.versionQueueFilter,
                eventsFilterList: action.receivedEventsList,
                employeesFilterList: state.employeesFilterList
            }
        case 'RECEIVE_VERSIONS':
            // Only accept the incoming data if it matches the most recent request. This ensures we correctly
            // handle out-of-order responses.
            if (action.versionQueueFilter === state.versionQueueFilter) {
                return {
                    queuedVersions: action.receivedVersions,
                    versionQueueFilter: action.versionQueueFilter,
                    eventsFilterList: state.eventsFilterList,
                    employeesFilterList: state.employeesFilterList
                };
            }
            break;
        default:
            // The following line guarantees that every action in the KnownAction union has been covered by a case above
            const exhaustiveCheck: never = action;
    }

    return state || unloadedState;
};
```

Calling my action creator here works:

```
componentWillMount() {
        this.props.requestVersions(this.props.versionQueueFilter);
    }
```

Calling my action creator here causes and error and I don't understand why:

```
handleFilterSubmission() { 
        this.props.requestVersions(this.props.versionQueueFilter);
    }
```

Note: I removed the function parameter on my submission handler just to confirm I wasn't having a problem with the data type of what was being passed.

I am calling that function from a child component that I am passing the reference to this function.

This is the child component reference in the parent:

```
<ASVersionQueueFilters 
    outerClassName=""
    htmlId=""
    filterVals={this.props.versionQueueFilter}
    employeesFilterList={this.props.employeesFilterList}
    eventsFilterList={this.props.eventsFilterList}
    onSubmitFunction={this.handleFilterSubmission}
/>
```

In the child component I have bound the passed function "onSubmitFunction" to an event handler function that ultimately calls the onSubmitFunction:

```
handleFormSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<EventTarget>) {
    event.preventDefault;
    let filterVals = {
        StartDate: moment(this.state.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        EndDate: moment(this.state.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        PieceType: [],
        EventType: [],
        EventID: this.state.selectedEventID,
        Employee: this.state.selectedEmployee
    }
    this.props.onSubmitFunction(filterVals);
}
```

The button fires the function and I can see in the console that the filter values are successfully passed back up to the parent function but calling my action creator this way keeps throwing the error.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if this is a TypeScript issue described here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your `handleFilterSubmission` with `this`. For that you might create a constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleFilterSubmission = this.handleFilterSubmission.bind(this);
}
```